# how to keep the variables that is match another dataset's one col

Tags: r, select, filter

I have a dataset :

```
df<-structure(list(EDC_file_name = c("e1", "e2", "e3", 
 "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8"), Tab = c("Demographics", 
 "Demographics", "PatientRegister", "PatientRegister", "PatientRegister", 
 "PatientRegister", "PatientConsent", "PatientConsent"), DatasetName = c("Demographics Merged", 
 NA, "Patient Register", NA, NA, NA, "Patient Consent", NA), GroupVar1 = c( "Subject", 
 NA, "Subject", NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

then I have another dataset

```
structure(list(varlist = c("Tab", "DatasetName"), lable = c("Tab", 
"Name of Dataset")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

how can I only keep the variables that is within varlist$Varlist?
`df_New<- df %>% select( %in% ?)` or `filter ...?`. Sorry for such simple question.

Comment: Do you want to have the variables from df that are in the rows of varlist$varlist? Try this, 
new_df <- df[,varlist$varlist]

Comment: df %>% inner_join(varlist, by = c('DatasetName' = 'Tab'))  But you need to have different column names in your second dataframe, here both columns have name 'Tab'.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram what about if i want to do the selection when I read in the data? such as I try to read in a list of files `for (i in 1:length(tbl)) assign(tbl[i], read.csv(file.path(paste0("C:/Project/",tbl[i]))))` what/how should I add filter when I read in the data I only read in the var in Varlist$varlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all_of` in `select` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% select(all_of(varlist$varlist))

#  Tab             DatasetName        
#  <chr>           <chr>              
#1 Demographics    Demographics Merged
#2 Demographics    NA                 
#3 PatientRegister Patient Register   
#4 PatientRegister NA                 
#5 PatientRegister NA                 
#6 PatientRegister NA                 
#7 PatientConsent  Patient Consent    
#8 PatientConsent  NA
```

Or if there are some values in `varlist$varlist` which are not present as column name in `df` use `any_of`.

```
df %>% select(any_of(varlist$varlist))
```

Comment: what if I want to do it to a list of file in my environment . `mget ` with `pattern="*.CS"`. What should I do?

Comment: You can do `read.csv(....) %>% select(any_of(varlist$varlist))` if you want to select columns while reading. Or if you have list of dataframes use `lapply` i.e `lapply(list_data, function(x) x %>%  select(any_of(varlist$varlist)))`. Also you should update your question with that information.

Comment: Thanks so much for prompt reply. I tried `lapply(mget(ls(pattern ="*.CS")),
        function(x) x <-x %>% select(Varlist$Var.name)))` and it runs without error code. However i did not see it filter our the variable. Did I miss anything ?

Comment: `data <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern ="*.CS")), function(x) x %>% select(Varlist$Var.name))` you should have list of selected columns in `data`. After that use `list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)` if you want the changed dataframes to be reflected in original object.

Comment: Thanks. Variables in the list are now selected. How can I get those data back to data.frame and substitute the data in environment?

Comment: `list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)`